# grouping values and bringing values into character string

Tags: r, dataframe

This is an example we can work with:

```
df <- tibble(a = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb"), 
             b = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), c = c(5,10,15,100,95,90))
df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  a         b     c
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 aaa       1     5
2 aaa       2    10
3 aaa       3    15
4 bbb       1   100
5 bbb       2    95
6 bbb       3    90
```

I want to group the values in column a and combine column b and c to a single string. The final result should look exactly like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  a         result
  <chr>     <chr>
1 aaa       {"1":5,"2":10,"3":15}
2 bbb       {"1":100,"2":95,"3":90}
```

and reads like this: aaa has 5 times 1, 10 times 2 and 15 times 3 etc.

I dont even know where to start honestly. Maybe with some dplyr::group_by and paste? I am glad for any hint.

Comment: hint: look at the `collapse`-argument from the paste (or paste0) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the entire artillery `paste`, `toString`, `sprintf`.

```
b <- by(df[-1], df$a, function(x) 
  sprintf("{%s}", toString(Reduce(paste0, c(x, "'", "':")[c(3, 1, 4, 2)]))))
data.frame(a=unique(df$a), result=do.call(rbind, as.list(b)), row.names=NULL)
#     a                    result
# 1 aaa   {'1':5, '2':10, '3':15}
# 2 bbb {'1':100, '2':95, '3':90}
```

*Note:* You may also use `'"'` quotes, will get escaped in display though.

Comment: Insane! Was this difficult for you? Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: May i also ask you for explanation? What the hell is the c(3,1,4,2) doing?

Comment: @Dutschke It is sorting the output of the `Reduce`. Try `Reduce(paste0, c(list("A", "B"), "'", "':")[c(3, 1, 4, 2)])` with and without it.

Comment: What, if i dont have 1 but 3 variables i wanna group_by? Like grouping by variables a, x and zand the rest stays the same? Those three variables would also be the first 3 columns in that tibble

Comment: I edited the question. If you could help again, i would be grateful forever

Comment: @Dutschke I would look into the `aggregate` function which is designed to "group by" an entire list of factors. I suggest to use your intended edit to ask a new question, in order to not produce a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the hint. I will try first, before i open a new question.